# Zoom only to a certain coordinate regardless of pointer location

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

I need the map to zoom in and out only to a certain coordinate regardless of where my pointer is located. For example, if I want the map to zoom to London the map will zoom to London even if my pointer is in the ocean or elsewhere. How do I implement that?

Answer (score 0):

There are not interactions in OpenLayers that do exactly that. Here's some suggestions for you:

A) You could try to constraint the extent and zoom of your map so that only the portion you want could be navigated.  See an example: [Zoom constrained](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/zoom-constrained.html), and API about [ol.View](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.View.html), more specifically see about the `extent`.

With this, you would control what the user can see/browse.  That would not be as perfect as "you can only zoom to London", but acceptable IMHO.

B) If you want to be more aggressive and restrict even more what the user can do when navigating, you could create **your own interactions** that would do exactly what you want.  I suppose you would need more than one, i.e. one for the "mouse scroll", one for "double-click" (both allow zooming in or out).

See how to create a [Custom Iteraction](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/custom-interactions.html) in OpenLayers.  You can get some inspiration from the existing ones in OL, but with tweeks that would make them do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Will have to find a way to work around this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the map center to some coordinate. You will need to know the coordinate beforehand.

```
var centerCoordinate = [0,0];
var view = map.getView();
view.setCenter (centerCoordinate);
```

This will move that map so that the map is centered around (0,0).
If you want, you can animate it by calling `view.animate`. There is an example at http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/animation.html.

Comment: Thanks, but I've already done that. My map is centered on a certain object while DragAndPan interaction is disabled and my task is to make it zoom to the centered object when a user scrolls. Although the map is centered, a user can zoom whenever he wants within his view.

Answer (score 0):

If somebody is interested, I achieved this by simply removing zoom iteraction and adding a listener to the native mousewheel event, which changes resolution of the map when triggered. There must be a better solution, but it works fine for me.